# unity c# Mathf.FloorToInt(-0.5) returns 0 (acts like Mathf.CielToInt)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, floor, math-functions

Here's the script reference document for [Mathf.FloorToInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) As you can see, it should round -0.5 down to -1. For some reason it seems to return it as 0 when used with my calculations.

I have two versions of the same functions that work in a very similar way but give different outputs. My code will only ever submit integers between 3 and 18 to these functions.

This version acts as if it were using Mathf.CielToInt (returns 0 in a case of statRoll = 9):

```
    public int getBonus(int statRoll)
{
    int result = Mathf.FloorToInt((statRoll - 10) / 2);
    return result;
}
```

This is the version that works (returns -1 in a case of statRoll = 9):

```
    public int getBonus(int statRoll)
{
    float initial = statRoll - 10;
    float divided = initial / 2;
    int result = Mathf.FloorToInt(divided);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: your simple problem is that in c#, for float constants like "7" and "2", you must write **7f** and **2f**.  it's that simple

Comment: @Fattie I usually write `7.0f` or just `7.0` if you are working with `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting bit by integer division. Both `statRoll` and `10` are `int` type, that makes `initial` actually a `int`.

Your first code is equivalent to

```
public int getBonus(int statRoll)
{
    int initial = statRoll - 10;
    int devisor = 2;
    int divided = initial / devisor;
    float castDevided = (float)divided
    int result = Mathf.FloorToInt(castDevided);
    return result;
}
```

When you do `-1 / 2` you have two ints, this evaluates to `0` not `-0.5` because the result must also be a int. The way to fix this is make one of the two values a `float`

```
public int getBonus(int statRoll)
{
    int result = Mathf.FloorToInt((statRoll - 10) / 2f); //adding f after a number makes it a float
    return result;
}
```

This makes the division between a `int` and a `float` which results in a float. The similar code would be

```
public int getBonus(int statRoll)
{
    int initial = statRoll - 10;
    float devisor = 2f;
    float divided = initial / devisor ;
    int result = Mathf.FloorToInt(divided);
    return result;
}
```